# Parameterize From Statement in SqlDataSource C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to Parameterize the from statement of an asp:SqlDatasource Select Command. My current command is hard coded:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsSPs" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AAPs_DevConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="select SPECIFIC_NAME from WIN_Dev.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'Procedure'">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

However I am looking for something more like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsSPs" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AAPs_DevConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="select SPECIFIC_NAME from @Path where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'Procedure'">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblDB" PropertyName="text" Name="Path" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Or even more preferable would be something like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsSPs" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AAPs_DevConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="select SPECIFIC_NAME from @Path.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'Procedure'">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblDB" PropertyName="text" Name="Path" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

All of these trys have come back failing. There is no way for me to know ahead of time what the DB is as the user can select it. Is there a way to do this? and if so what is it? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to write Dynamic Query/Procedure for your requirement,

```
Create Proc Get_From_Dynamic_Table
@tablename varchar(50)
as
begin
declare @sqlQuery nvarchar(100)
Set @sqlQuery = 'Select * from '+@tablename
exec sp_executesql @sqlQuery
end
```

Note: Code not tested.